# Dimensions of a differential matrix

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $h:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and that $g:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $g(a,b,c)=h(ab,ac)$. How to find the differential matrix dimensions for the differential d$h$?

My feeling is that the matrix should be a $(2 \times 3)$ matrix, since the function $g$ has two coordinate functions and three variables. How can I make sure I am correct?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Figured it out.  In general, for a function $f: \mathbb{R^p} \to \mathbb{R^q}$, the dimensions for the differential are simply ($q \times p$).

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Comment: Did you mean to look for the matrix dimensions for $Dg$ or $Dh$?

Comment: In general, if $f:A \to B$, then $Df(x):A \to B$.

Comment: I'm looking for d$g$.  But shouldn't d$g$ and d$h$ have the same dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Think of $g= h\circ f$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by
\begin{align}
f(a, b, c) = (ab, ac). 
\end{align}

Then apply the chain rule to $g = h \circ f$.

Comment: By the chain rule we would have d$g$= $\frac{\partial h}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial a} +\frac{\partial h}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial b} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial c}$, right?